# extract nested json value with mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

| customfields |
| --- |
| '{"6": {"name": "Confirmed?", "type": "Checkbox", "value": "true"}, "7": {"name": "Estimated/Actual Ship date", "type": "Date", "value": "2022-08-08 00:00:00"}' |

I'd like to extract true from id 6. I've tried
`select json_extract(customFields, '$.6.value')`

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, it's missing a closing `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote `6` since it's not a valid identifier.

```
select json_extract(customfields, '$."6".value') from mytable;
```

This is in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-paths):

> A period followed by a key name names the member in an object with the given key. **The key name must be specified within double quotation marks if the name without quotes is not legal within path expressions (for example, if it contains a space).**